# Point inside rectangle

Tags: c, point, rectangles

I wanted to ask if this function is correct. It should check if point is inside rectangle and if it is then print it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
}point;

typedef struct {
  point A;
  point B;
}rectangle;

int main() {
rectangle s;
point T;
printf("Enter rectangle A point x coordinate :\n" );
scanf("%d", &s.A.x);
printf("Enter rectangle A point y coordinate :\n" );
scanf("%d", &s.A.y);
printf("Enter rectangle B point x coordinate :\n" );
scanf("%d", &s.B.x);
printf("Enter rectangle B point y coordinate :\n" );
scanf("%d", &s.B.y);    
printf("\nrectangle - A(%d, %d), B(%d, %d) \n", s.A.x, s.A.y, s.B.x, s.B.y );

for(int i =0; i<2; i++){ 
printf ("X: ");
scanf ("%d", &T.x);
printf ("Y: ");
scanf ("%d", &T.y);
} 

int is_inside(point A, point B){
if((s.A.x <= T.x) && (T.x <= s.B.x) && (s.A.y <= T.y) && (T.y <= s.B.y)) printf("Point (%d, %d)is inside rectangle \n",T.x, T.y);
else printf("No");
}
return 0;
}
```

Added whole code maybe it would be more clearly to you guys.

Answer (score 7):

This function is incorrect. It compiles, but it does not do what you want it to do<sup>*</sup>.

Mathematical conditions such as this one

```
x0 <= X <= x1
```

are written as follows in C:

```
x0 <= X && X <= x1
```

Your condition should look like this:

```
if (s.A.x<=T.x && T.x<=s.B.x && s.A.y<=T.y && T.y<=s.B.y)
```

---

<sup>*</sup> The result of comparing `s.A.x<= T.x` is then compared to `s.B.x`

Comment: @Atskalunas My guess would be that you are not passing in the right values. Set a break point on the line of the `if` in the debugger, and examine the variables used in the condition.

Comment: On some letter for example: A, B it says not found in current context.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `if (a<=b<=c)` because it evaluates from left to right and it's causing you a problem.

first `a<=b` evaluates to either `0` or `1` which again compared to third term `c`

use `a<=b && b<=c` syntax

So, In your case it would be like

```
if ((s.A.x <= T.x) && (T.x <= s.B.x ) && (s.A.y <=T.y )&& (T.y <= s.B.y))
```

This statement says that `s.A.x is less than equal to T.x` and `T.x is less than or equal to s.B.x` AND `s.A.y less than equal to T.y and T.y is less than equal to s.B.y`

Answer (score 1):

- You are missing function's return type
- You need to evaluate the boundaries using

  ```
  ((s.A.x <= T.x) && (T.x <= s.B.x) && (s.A.y <= T.y) && (T.y <= s.B.y))
  ```
- The other problem is:
  In your function's printf, you are recursively calling is_inside(A,B). Supposing the if condition turns to be true, you will get yourself in an infinite loop.

  ```
  printf("Point (%f, %f)is inside rectangle \n", T.x, T.y);
  ```

Comment: @Atskalunas you need to printf your points, instead you are calling your function recursively.